# Any package builder for windows (like Inno Setup) which uses python

Tags: python, windows, package, inno-setup

I know python and I am working on a project where we are using Inno setup. Is there any package builder where I can write the setup-code in python?

Comment: I don't think you'll find any such package builder (easily), because if it uses python, it creates a dependency on python. If Inno Setup is giving you problems, I recommend ISTool. It's got a simple interface and you don't need to use the low-level Pascal for most things.

Comment: Python isn't really a native language to Windows so whatever you find will have to fully compile the script. Pascal scritp isn't that hard to pick up if you know ay other languages.

Comment: is pascal native on windows? or it is also compiled fully by inno?

Comment: thanks @darkphoenix and Deanna.. I got the answer.. I will go with Inno and will look into ISTool..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python together with inno. With inno you can collect all the user data which you need, and with python you can do all the other work with this user data. To do that you need to include the python files in your setup. During your setup you need to extract the files and then you can call your python scripts.